# Do classes hinder the execution time of a program (as opposed to an implementation using only free functions)?

Tags: c++, function, oop

There is a ""rumor"" that I've heard in the competitive programming community that an approach to implementing a data structure, for example, using classes would render a much slower time than an implementation basing itself on a purely functional paradigm. I've tested this out (on *my* recursive segment tree implementation using classes then only functions that were practically the same) with a completely random generator (the queries and the updates had an equal probability in appearing in the testcase), and the results concured with the hypothesis; the purely functional program averaged (~7 seconds) twice better than the object-oriented implementation (~12.8 seconds) in high (5 mil - 10 mil queries+updates) inputs.

So, my question is, why would this difference is so accentuated, and why does it even happen in the first place?

Thank you for reading this!

Here's the code(maybe I messed up something and that's why all of this happened):

The class implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; //poor practice :P

class AINT {
  int tree[1048700];
  public:
    void update(int val, int poz, int node=1, int cl=1, int cr=500000) {
      if(cl==cr) {
        tree[node]=val;
        return;
      }
      int mid=(cl+cr)/2;
      if(poz<=mid)
        update(val,poz,2*node,cl,mid);
      else
        update(val,poz,2*node+1,mid+1,cr);
      tree[node]=max(tree[2*node],tree[2*node+1]);
    }
    int query(int l, int r, int node=1, int cl=1, int cr=500000) {
      if(l<=cl && cr<=r) {
        return tree[node];
      }
      int mid=(cl+cr)/2,a=0,b=0;
      if(l<=mid)
        a=query(l,r,2*node,cl,mid);
      if(mid<r)
        b=query(l,r,2*node+1,mid+1,cr);
      return max(a,b);
    }
}aint;

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  for(int i=0,t,x,y; i<n; i++) {
    cin>> t >> x>> y;
    if(t==1)
      aint.update(y,x);
    else
      cout << aint.query(x,y) <<'\n'; // i added the output (which I then redirected to a file) because it seems relevant to also print the values (otherwise the compiler might just ignore the unused result)
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the purely functional implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int tree[1048700];
void update(int val, int poz, int node=1, int cl=1, int cr=500000) {
  if(cl==cr) {
    tree[node]=val;
    return;
  }
  int mid=(cl+cr)/2;
  if(poz<=mid)
    update(val,poz,2*node,cl,mid);
  else
    update(val,poz,2*node+1,mid+1,cr);
  tree[node]=max(tree[2*node],tree[2*node+1]);
}
int query(int l, int r, int node=1, int cl=1, int cr=500000) {
  if(l<=cl && cr<=r) {
    return tree[node];
  }
  int mid=(cl+cr)/2,a=0,b=0;
  if(l<=mid)
    a=query(l,r,2*node,cl,mid);
  if(mid<r)
    b=query(l,r,2*node+1,mid+1,cr);
  return max(a,b);
}
int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  for(int i=0,t,x,y; i<n; i++) {
    cin>> t >> x>> y;
    if(t==1)
      update(y,x);
    else
      x=query(x,y); // i added the output (which I then redirected to a file) because it seems relevant to also print the values (otherwise the compiler might just ignore the unused result)
    x=y+x*x;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the generator:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int rand(int a, int b) {
  return rand()%(b-a+1)+a;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  srand(atoi(argv[1]));
  int n;
  n=10000000;
  cout << n << '\n';
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int t=rand(0,1),x=rand(1,500000),y=rand(1,500000);
    if(t==0 && x>y)
      swap(x,y);
    cout << t << ' ' <<x << ' ' <<y <<'\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: you should read the tag description of `purely-functional` because it does not apply here

Comment: how did you measure the time? Did you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i added -O2 as a flag when making the calculations

Comment: it is still questionable to call this "functional-programming". Again tag description: "...avoiding side effects and change of state". Your functions are all about side effects and modifying a global state. Don't confuse using functions and avoiding object orientation with functional programming

Comment: There's output in the first one (class version) that isn't in the second (functional). That will add a considerable amount of execution time.

Comment: Looks like in your example, all you did was place your functions into a class.  This really not OOP.  Your examples will probably not differ in speed, since the functions are the same.

Answer (score -1):

It depends if your class defines constructors or destructors or inherits from another class and especially if it uses inherited virtual functions like:

```
class Animal{
virtual void makeSound(){}
virtual std::string getName(){}
};

class Dog : Animal{
void makeSound(){}
std::string getName(){}
};
```

than there is overhead for using the virtual function table. I know for a fact that virtual destructors can really kill performance. However just moving a bunch of functions into a class will not hurt your performance at all.

It's also arguable that your example of 'pure functional' is not even close to the tag definition.

If you meant using a bunch of functions in the global namespace vs functions wrapped in class, there is no performance differences if you compile with -O3 optimizations or Release Mode on MSVC.

Although if your not going to use the features of classes and you just want a way to organize and find functions use a namespace like:

```
namespace animal {
namespace dog {
    void bark() {}
    }
}

animal::dog::bark();
```

Also please be careful how your measuring performance, if you're timing `std::cout or std::cin` you're going to get terrible numbers IO is always very slow and totally inconsistent.

You would never measure IO operations if you can help it. I suggest you watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG4jexlSAjc

by The Cherno a.k.a. Yan Chernokov , his tutorials are fantastic.